# ASP.net Core Razor Pages - Get HTML of a specified div in Code-Behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am trying to get a specified div on my page in code-behind to convert the html to rtf using [HtmlToOpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlToOpenXml.dll/).

At this stage I have a hidden textarea/input to save the html into a Request I can use in the code-behind. But either way using javascript to set the text inside of the textarea/input sets some weird whitespaces, which get converted to the OpenXML as well.

So basically I am wondering how to get the content of a specific div-Tag in code-behind, so the converter can use the html.

For everyone wondering why I need that: I am using [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/tinymce/) for the user to generate the basic design of a document, which contains lists of sentences with dropdowns and inputs which will get filled on using the tool. These entries get pasted into the div and should render as text on download and not as dropdowns or inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the specific html by using `$("#divname").get(0).outerHTML;` and then post it to server side:

```
<div id="thisdiv">   //will get div by this id
    <div>Hello</div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Send" onclick="SendDiv()" />

@section Scripts
{
<script>
    function SendDiv() {
        var divhtml = $("#thisdiv").get(0).outerHTML;
        $.ajax({
            url: "your path",
            data: { mydiv: divhtml },
            method: 'POST'
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

Result:

[image]